# Brick wall with maximum height 3

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given n same-sized rectangular bricks. We want to build a wall with these constraints:

- All bricks should be horizontal.
- We can put a brick on two other bricks, such that the middle of the top brick is on the border of two other bricks.
- The maximum height of the wall should be 3.
- Bricks on the first row (the ground) should stick together.

For example, if we have 4 bricks, we can build the wall in 3 ways. If we have 6 bricks, we can make the wall in 9 ways.

Some examples of this recursive function are:

$f(1) = {0 \choose 0} = 1$

$f(2) = {1 \choose 1} = 1$

$f(3) = {2 \choose 0} + {1 \choose 1} = 1 + 1 = 2$

$f(4) = {3 \choose 0} + {2 \choose 1} = 1 + 2 = 3$

$f(5) = {4 \choose 0} + {3 \choose 1} + {2 \choose 2} = 1 + 3 + 1 = 5$

$f(6) = {5 \choose 0} + {4 \choose 1} + {3 \choose 2} + {2 \choose 2}{1 \choose 1} = 1 + 4 + 3 + 1 = 9$

This is the illustration of how we can build the wall using 6 bricks:

[image: Building the wall using 6 bricks]

I tried to find a recurrence relation for this problem, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Related to [OEIS A005169](https://oeis.org/A005169), which is the same, except for the height limit.

Comment: Equivalent to [OEIS A239909](https://oeis.org/A239909), which gives the formula as $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}-a_{n-4}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, deriving a sixth-order linear recurrence.

A wall with $k$ bricks in the bottom row can be decomposed into $k$ diagonals with slope $-1$. The first diagonal contains only the leftmost brick in the bottom row. After that each diagonal can be at most one brick longer than the previous one, up to a maximum length of $3$ bricks. Thus, we are in effect counting the sequences $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_k\rangle$ such that

- $a_i\in\{1,2,3\}$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$,
- $a_1=1$,
- $a_{i+1}-a_i\le 1$ for $i=1,\ldots,k-1$, and
- $a_1+\ldots+a_k=n$.

Let $b_n$ be the number of such sequences, and for $i=1,2,3$ let $b_{n,i}$ be the number of such sequences ending in $i$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
b_{n,3}&=b_{n-3,2}+b_{n-3,3}=b_{n-3}-b_{n-3,1}\\
b_{n,2}&=b_{n-2}\\
b_{n,1}&=b_{n-1}\,,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
b_{n}&=b_{n,1}+b_{n,2}+b_{n,3}\\
&=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}-b_{n-3,1}\\
&=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}-b_{n-4}\,,
\end{align*}$$

with initial values $b_0=1$, $b_1=1$, $b_2=1$, $b_3=2$, $b_4=3$, and $b_5=5$. The next few values are easily computed:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
b_n:&1&1&1&2&3&5&9&15&26&45&77
\end{array}$$

By the way, if the height were limited to $2$, we would simply be getting the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: The series you wrote can result negative numbers. For example, $b_{68}=-327557302$

Comment: @JohnMike: No, $b_{68}\approx 1.03244\times 10^{15}$.

Comment: There is some error here. $b_8$ and $b_9$ should match the related sequence I mentioned in comments. Specifically, $b_8=26$ and $b_9=45$. See my second comment above for the correct sequence and formula.

Comment: The error is in $b_{n,2}$, which should be $b_{n,2}=b_{n-2}$. Excluding $b_{n-2,3}$ excludes sequences ending in $32$, which are valid.

Comment: @DanielMathias: Thank you very much; you’re absolutely right. (And for the record, the correct value for $b_{68}$ is actually approximately $3.79051\times 10^{15}$.)